# Passing in props to a function from an NPM package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have a simple React application, where i want to use the 
`react-timeago` npm module

and i looked at the documentation, where there i a function that i want to use

```
formatter (optional)
A function that takes four arguments:

value : An integer value, already rounded off
unit : A string representing the unit in english. This could be one of:
'second'
'minute'
'hour'
'day'
'week'
'month'
'year'
suffix : A string. This can be one of
'ago'
'from now'
epochSeconds: The result of Date.now() or the result of a custom now prop.
nextFormatter: A function that takes no arguments and gives you the result of the defaultFormatter using the same arguments above.
```

this is displayed as a prop, in the documentation, but how can i pass in the arguments to the function as props?

```
     <TimeAgo date={this.state.time} formatter={/*how can i pass in the arguments to the function */} live={true}/>
```

i have called the component here, but I'm in doubt about how to pass in the proper props to the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give a function to the `formatter` prop that `react-timeago` will use internally.

**Example**

```
<TimeAgo
  date={this.state.time}
  formatter={(value, unit, suffix) => `${value} ${unit} ${suffix}`}
  live={true}
/>
```

Comment: But do i fill in the values in the template literal?, or how cna i pass in my arguments?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin Those arguments will be given to the function when `react-timeago` calls it, it's just what you want to name them. (foo, bar, baz) => `${foo} ${bar} ${baz}` would work just as well, and you can of course reference other variables in the current scope.

Comment: ahh just like a normal function? so for example
` formatter={(value=0, unit='minute', suffix='ago') => `${value} ${unit} ${suffix}`} `

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that `formatter` takes in a function, so you either have to give it one of their predefined functions, or a function you define yourself.

Importantly, this is a **callback function**, so you won't need to call it or send it parameters. The `<TimeAgo ...` component will invoke the function with the parameters listed in the documentation, in order to produce the final, formatted string.

One of their formatter functions:

```
import frenchStrings from 'react-timeago/lib/language-strings/fr'
import buildFormatter from 'react-timeago/lib/formatters/buildFormatter'
```